# Need to the ion-card over the ion-header

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm just trying to show the ion-card above the ion-header but its not works.

I have added my html code as well css code.
Can anyone help me I'm stuck from 2 days

[Actual Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED4H3.png)

```css
ion-toolbar{
    --background:#aac9ff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    border-radius: 0 0 20% 20%;
}
.date {
    margin-top: -180px;
    z-index: 10;
    padding: 6px;
    box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 45px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 16%);
    border-radius: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<ion-header [translucent]="true" class="ion-no-border">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>
      Age Calculator
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true" padding>

  <div id="container">
    <ion-card class="date">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col size="12">Today Date</ion-col>
        <ion-col size="12">
          <ion-item lines="none">
            <ion-icon name="calendar-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>
              <ion-datetime placeholder="23-07-2020"  [(ngModel)]="currentDate" display-format="DD-MM-YYYY"></ion-datetime>
            </ion-label>
            <ion-icon name="chevron-forward" slot="end"></ion-icon>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      </ion-card>
      </div>
      </ion-content>
```

Comment: If I run this snippet then I am not getting result as posted in image. Please correct the sample.

Comment: That is not possible here because I'm using ionic